# writing secure clients in Java

Tags: java

When a user uses a *client* like Twitter Client to update their status message, they have to provide their username and password. The *server* then authenticates the user and updates status message.

My question is how to ensure the security of such sensitive information over the internet.
Is JSSE the correct way to go about it?

What points are to be kept in mind when writing such a client?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

From the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#WhySSL):

> Once the client and the server are comfortable with each other's identity, SSL provides privacy and data integrity through the encryption algorithms it uses. This allows sensitive information, such as credit card numbers, to be transmitted securely over the Internet.

So yes, JSSE is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

For Twitter specifically, they have a whole page dedicated to [security best practices](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/security_best_practices).  A lot of those things apply to applications generally, so it's worth a read.  In a nutshell, they highly recommend a protocol called OAuth to handle the password safely, and it's going to be mandatory soon.  The actual programming environment you use is much less important than the process you use.

Answer (score 0):

For twitter use OAuth instead of basic authentication. Its much more secure way to authenticate users in your case. Some info could be found here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth